# "make xconfig" raises a Qt error

Tags: debian, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, qt

When I call `make xconfig` in my linux kernel source directory, I get the following error

```
scripts/kconfig/qconf  Kconfig
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x142
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x300000d
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x300000e
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x300000e
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x300000e
```

and the window which opens, titled *Linux/x86 4.9.130 Kernel Configuration* is just empty. That means I cannot use the Qt front-end for the kernel configuration. I have been using the make targets `menuconfig` and `nconfig` so far, but I would also like to be able to use the graphical Qt front-end as it is more convenient.

Note that in my Ubuntu that I have installed along-side Debian, it works. I have compared all **Qt4**-related packages installed under Ubuntu with those installed in Debian, and each package with `qt` in its name, except those in version `5.9.5` as they are Qt5, is also installed under Debian.

Comment: Just a thought: are you trying to run `make xconfig` as root? Don't do that. It's a bad idea even with `make menuconfig`.

Comment: Thanks @JohanMyréen. Yes, as root, having switched to root with `su`. I just tried it as normal user, and it works. In Ubuntu I have always done it as root, after I've typed `sudo -s`. Why does it work as normal user? Also, why is `make xconfig` as root a bad idea.

Comment: For security reasons, by default, root (or any other user) can't connect to a user's X server. As a rule of thumb, restrict your user privileges to the required minimum. Superuser powers is not needed to configure and compile software. If the permissions on a directory in `/usr/src`is a problem, a better solution is to enable access to the user's group instead of running the whole build process as root. Only do the `make modules_install` and `make install` steps as root.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I know you don't actually need root privileges for kernel configuration. On the other hand, in the manual `/usr/share/kernel-package/docs/Kernel.htm` in the `kernel-package` (for Ubuntu) package, the author argued "*Login as root to do this type of administration.  Some of the other kernel-building documents that I've seen make a big deal about what parts of the procedure can be done as a non-root user.  I never bother with that.  To me, kernel building and installing are administrative tasks, and I just stay root the whole time.  It's simpler that way*", which had convinced me.

Comment: @JohanMyréen: Okay, say I want to use `make xconfig` as normal user, but with as few relaxations of the restrictions on the files in the directory as possible. How would I do that? I could change the group of all files to a group the user is a member of and allow write permission for that group, can't I?

Comment: Yes, you could change the group on all the files, or you could change the owner of all files and directories to your user id, or you could `git clone` the Linux kernel repository to your home directory, in which case the files would be owned by you automatically. (Though there probably are some Ubuntu specific changes in the kernel shipped with Ubuntu).

Comment: Okay. Since the actual question was about why the Qt frond-end didn't open, and you answered that in your second comment (root cannot connect to user's X server), you could make that an answer, and I will accept it. @JohanMyréen